# Get Tasks list from Google account using username and password

Tags: google-tasks-api, google-tasks

i am developing an desktop application in which i have to get task list from google account (as per requirement )  in analysing i didnot find any way to get it done as i didnot have much idea about Google Task Api and in the documentation provided at google @ https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/  
i didnot find any authentication mechanism (where a client enters his username and password of his gmail account and get the tasks) as i saw it only uses client key and secret key which is not expected from the user to fill in 
so please suggest is there any way to get the google tasks using Username And Password of client ?


Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First follow the steps outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/firstapp) and then see the [Authorize Request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/auth) page. The recommended method is OAuth2, so the user will never give you his username and password, instead he will share with you an access token.

Comment: hi thanks for your help. can you please share any code snippet in .Net of Javascript this would be a your great contribution